# jQuery UI Tabs - How to add Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI Tabs in my page...

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

exemple:  http://jsfiddle.net/thiagoluga/hk9a89y1/

Now I want to remove my current tabs and add new Tabs... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of dynamically adding and removing tabs.

[Add/remove tabs using jquery](http://www.kilbot.com.au/web-development/code-examples/add-remove-tabs-using-jquery/)

Hoping it helps.

Cheers !!